# React lib for drill down tables

Tags: reactjs

I am searching for a library to create drill-down tables in a react application.

With a behavior like this:

- Table with a view count of everything per medium and month
- When you click on movie you get to the view count of all movies by type and month
- When you click on action you get to the view count of action movies by month

Overview:
[image: Overview]

Table by type:
[image: Type]

Table by title:
[image: Title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React-Table` has a feature that name is `Sub-component` when you click on a row or cell you can . for more information see this [React-Table Sub-component](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/sub-components)

In `sub component` you can show some component or also show another react table